# rosserial debs for rosserial_arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing rosserial to use with an arduino and in the setup page, it has the cryptic lines:
"If you installed rosserial from debs, all you have to do is copy the rosserial_arduino/libraries directory into your Arduino sketchbook. After restarting your IDE, you should see ros_lib listed under examples."

How do you get the rosserial debs?

It goes on to say how to install from source, but I'd prefer to use debs if I can find them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11217/rosserial-debs-for-rosserial_arduino/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have already setup your ROS system following [these instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu), you just have to:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-rosserial
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2011-09-15**:
Thanks!  Is that documented somewhere?  I added it to the wiki page.